# Same library included from two libraries

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, linker-errors

I get error:

`ld: 24 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

because I have two libraries that both use `GTMLogger.o`.

```
/Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-name/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a(GTMLogger.o)
/Users/***/project-name/Libraries/Framework/Framework.framework/Framework(GTMLogger.o)
```

One library is included as cocoapod and the other is included manually. Second library cant be included as cocoapod.

I need both libraries and just want to know is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You use one CocoaPods for `libGoogleToolboxForMac`, right? The other one is a static library too?

Comment: @Larme I use CocoaPods for Firebase/Messaging actually, and it includes GoogleToolboxForMac, also as other framework which isn't CocoaPods